# Accessing the FB user id I got from passport JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, session-cookies, passport.js

I am having an issue trying to use the FB user ID I got from the passport JS policy I created. In my application I let the user login to FB, and created a user in my DB if there isn't a matching one already.

I have a pretty basic node JS app with one place where I manage all my views (using hogan engine for now). So inside my app.js file when I do:

```
app.get('/myaccount', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
      console.log('-- User ID:' + req.user.id );
      res.render('myaccount', { user: req.user });
});
```

I get the right userId. For example mine is XXXXXXX8342620263.

But in the client side (my hjs file) Im trying to use the same userId and I get very similar but different ID.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Populate the spends table
        console.log('==Populate the spends for my account ' + {{user.id}});
        populateMyData({{user.id}});
    });
</script>
```

for my account I get  *XXXXXXX8342620264* instead of  *XXXXXXX8342620263*.
This is driving me insane.
any suggestions?

I even tried to do

```
var userId = {{user.id}};    
userId--;
```

and for some reason I still get that same wrong userId.

Comment: I suggest templating into DOM instead of javascript, if handlebars escapes quotes like EJS and jade: `<meta id="myJSON" data-userid="{{JSON.stringify(user.id)}}">`; `var userid = JSON.parse($('#myJSON').data('userid'))`